# Is there a way to use dplyr::bind_rows without collecting data frames from the database?

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

Is there a way to use `bind_rows()` on a set of data frames without first collecting them from the database?

Say I've defined a couple dplyr query tables:

```
mydatabase  <- src_mysql('database')
table1  <- tbl(mydatabase,"table1")
table2  <- tbl(mydatabase,"table3")

foo  <-  table1 %>% filter(id > 10) %>% select(id)
bar  <-  table2 %>% select(id)
```

I'd like to be able to join foo and bar together--in essence, I'd like to perform a union on the two subqueries without having to drop to SQL. However, when I try that, I get an error because I'm trying to join two tbl_sql objects, rather that real data frames:

```
unioned_data_frame  <- bind_rows(foo,bar)
```

> Error: incompatible sizes (1 != 8)

Any suggestions? In this toy example, writing the whole query in SQL wouldn't be a problem, but of course, in real life, foo and bar are often significantly more complicated.

Comment: I could use `dplyr::union()` which would handle the heavy lifting in terms of SQL query, but it doesn't have the extremely handy .id argument that `bind_rows()` does. 

Perhaps I'll have to go without?

Comment: I think you want `dplyr::union_all()` in order to perfectly replicate `bind_rows()`, but yes, you'd probably have to use `mutate()` to create an additional column with the identifier, which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::union()` will do the SQL `union()` action, although it's important to note that that `dplyr::union()` will remove duplicate rows (like the SQL version). Using `dplyr::union_all()` keeps duplicate rows like `bind_rows()`.

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to get benefits of `bind_rows()`, particularly the very useful `.id` argument.